# Can I use secure Travis env variables in .travis.yml to upload to PyPI?

Tags: travis-ci, pypi

I am trying to have Travis to upload to PyPI using the following configuration

```
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  user: P403n1x87
  password: $PYPI_PASSWORD
  distributions: "sdist bdist_wheel"
  on:
    tags: true
```

However, the upload fails with

```
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

The variable `PYPI_PASSWORD` is defined as a secure env variable for the repository on Travis. The official Travis documentation instructs to use travis-encrypt and to put the result in the `secure` property under `password:`.

Is my alternative method not valid at all? Is  there an alternative that involves the use of env variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the method I have used works fine. My password contains characters that need to be escaped since they are fed directly to bash.

Comment: The password can also be surrounded by `"` (unless it contains `"`).  I also had to learn the hard way that tags are not on branches (i.e. if you specify an travis environment variable to be available for one branch only, it won't at all be available for tag builds)